# Does In-Memory Realm have the copy of disk persisted Realm data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Just trying to understand, when we try to access an object using an in-memory realm instance, does it replicate the disk persisted realm data at that moment or will it be a clean realm instance with no data in the objects.

I do understand that both the realm instances point to the same object schema but still confused.

I have both **disk-persistence and in-memory realm in my project**.

When I try to query the disk-persisted realm the data objects are returned if exists while on the other hand the if I perform the same query on in-memory realm it always returns `0` objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The in-memory Realm will be a clean Realm instance. It does not interfere with any other realm (on-disk or elswhere). All entries will be gone, once your application is terminated.

You can even have multiple in-memory Realms running at once, e.g. to have a clean database for each unit test class. Just make sure you use a different `inMemoryIdentifier` for each test.

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()
config.inMemoryIdentifier = self.name // use the test class name as identifier

let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
return realm
```

Comment: is there a way that I could load the disk-persisted realm into in-memory realm?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This answers my question. Hence marking it correct.